# Remove parts of value by comma | Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to remove the values ​​after the first comma. It is possible that there will be more values ​​and commas.

Expected result:

```
8-1 
10-1
2-5 
5-8
```

ss from Logger.log for var Id 
[image]

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var FirstRow = 7;
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - FirstRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = Sheet.getRange(FirstRow,3,RowRange,9);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  
  
  for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++){
     var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
     var Id = CurrentRow[0]; //col with ID Sheet1
     var firstId = Id.map(vA=>[vA.split(',')[1]]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply this operation for all the input data and get the first `[0]` element of the resulting array:

```
data.map(vA=>[vA.split(',')[0]])
```

### Code snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const avals = sh.getRange('A1:A4').getValues().flat();
  const bvals = avals.map(vA=>[vA.split(',')[0]]);
  sh.getRange(1,2,bvals.length,1).setValues(bvals);
}
```

**Sheet used for code snippet:**

[image]

Make sure you format the input text as `plain text`, otherwise google sheets consider the input data to be `dates` or alternatively use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) instead of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) but I guess you have already figured out that part because `console.log` returns the correct input.

### Updated answer based on your edited question:

Modify your current `for` loop as follows:

```
for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++){
     var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
     var Id = CurrentRow[0]; //col with ID Sheet1
     var newId = Id.split(',')[0];
     console.log(newId);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!, but unfortunately I get an error "TypeError: data.map is not a function"

Comment: @AdOne what is `data` in your case? see my code snippet. I define `avals` as a 1D array coming from `getValues().flat()` so it is a 1D array of values. What do you use?

Comment: Hmm My code looks like this. var Id contains data as in the screenshot from Logger Log. I tried add Id.flat () it also gets error

Comment: @AdOne [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65901010/edit) your question to include your code there..

Comment: @AdOne you want to do this for column C only right? the values `8-1,9-1` are in column C?

Comment: Yes, all values are in column C

Comment: @AdOne and where do you wanna paste the new values? back to column C again or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to declare them in the same format as they were and use them for the rest of the script